# Present View from SKScene in Xcode 6 with Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene, xcode6

I have a basic game running exclusively as SKScene. I would like to transition to a view called testview.xib but I cannot find any Swift examples of how to do so.

Here's my attempt based on other answers

```
let vc = UIViewController(nibName: "testview", bundle: nil) as UIViewController
self.view.window.rootViewController.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but the application fails with an error "Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode 0x0)"

The code for moving between SKScenes is

```
var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(1)
var scene:SKScene = otherScene(size: self.size)
self.view.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

Comment: Can you clarify where you are having trouble? What happens when you try the code you posted? Does your app crash, do you get any specific errors, etc.?

Comment: Sure. I have a view called testview.xib. I am trying to present this view from a SKScene in iOS 7.1 SDK running xcode 6.4. I have recently tried `let vc = UIViewController(nibName: "testview", bundle: nil) as UIViewController
            
        self.view.window.rootViewController.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
` and this fails with "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"

Comment: Thanks. At a glance, it that looks like it should work. Can you edit your original question and add the entire stack trace? I'm not sure offhand why you'd get `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`, but the stack trace should give a bit more context.

Comment: That didn't really shed any light on it, sorry. Have you tried upgrading to Xcode6 Beta5 (you said you're running Xcode 6.4; I assume you meant Beta4)? `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` can be caused by the compiler emitting the wrong instructions for the CPU, so it could be a swift compiler bug.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I downloaded and tried to compile the same code in 6 beta 5 - and I got 5 errors lol. Most of them around my SKScene classes not implementing its superclass's required members - blah! But also ` self.view.window.rootViewController.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)' - UIWindow does not have a member named 'rootViewController' - really lol

Comment: Ok well I think I fixed that SKScene error but and changed the presentviewcontroller to self.view.window?.rootViewController.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) but I get the very same compiler error :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59284/discussion-between-mike-s-and-cudds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with calling `presentViewController()` from within the `init()` method of the class. Basically, you can't call `presentViewController()` before the view/controller is setup; instead, you'll typically want to call it when some action occurs (button press, touch event, etc.).

The issue that was starting to be discussed in the comments and then moved in to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59284/discussion-between-mike-s-and-cudds) was solved by loading the view controller from a storyboard instead of a xib.  NOTE: An xib would work, but it's trickier to setup than a storyboard is.